# Cross compilation for x86-64 target on arm64 host

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, apple-m1

I'm trying to find a way to do cross-compilation for x86-64 target on an arm64 machine, the gcc version used is 4.8.5 (Old version. I know...).
My host is an Apple M1 machine, and the program can be built only on Linux.

I tried creating a docker container that emulates x86-64 using QEMU -  but its terribly slow.

I'm now trying to use a linux container (or a vm) and looking for a arm64 to x86 cross compiler, I have used arm64 to x86-64 compilers in the past, but can't find the reverse one.

Thanks